# Как в Freemarker проверить существования ключа в Map и вывести значения?

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

Подскажите пожалуйста!
Как в Freemarker проверить существования ключа в Map и вывести значения?

У меня во `view` есть следующий `macro`

```
<#macro addMessage errorMessage = {}>
// some code

</#macro>
```

Мне нужно проверить если в `errorMessage` некий `ключ`, и если да, вывести какое-то значение и его `value`

На PHP я бы сделал так

```
<div class="<?= array_key_exists("foo", errorMessage) ? "is-invalid" : "" ?>">
```

Нашел конструкцию с `IF`

```
<#if errorMessage.foo??>
   the map contains a key called color
</#if>
```

Но она не удобная...

Так же нашел конструкцию с:

```
${foo?then('Y', 'N')}
```

Но тут я не понимаю как передать ему ключ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ:

```
${(errorMessage.foo??)?then('is-invalid', '')}
```